# Imported image roles are lost on update in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, import, product-images, thumbnail, small-image

I use an import script to create products with associated images that are assigned to roles `thumbnail` and `small image`.

It works well, products and images are imported and they display as `thumbnail` and `small image` on the front-end website.

But when I try to edit one of those products via Magento admin, the roles `thumbnail` and `small image` are not selected in the UI and saving the product will make this image's roles to be lost.

Why may cause effective `thumbnail` to not be detected as one when loading the `Edit` product page? Did I do something the bad way in this import script?

Any clue of what the source of this problem can be?

Here is the import code:

```
    $product->setMediaGallery(array(
                                  'images' => array(),
                                  'values' => array()
                              ));

    foreach ($product['pictures'] as $key => $picture)
    {
        $image_url = $picture['picture'];
        $image_ext = pathinfo($image_url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image_url));
        $image = $this->_imageContentFactory->create()
            ->setType('image/jpeg')
            ->setName($sku . '-' . $key . '.' . $image_ext)
            ->setBase64EncodedData($imageData);

        $entry = $this->_productAttributeMediaGalleryEntryFactory->create();
        $entry->setContent($image);
        $entry->setMediaType('image');
        if (0 == $key)
            $entry->setTypes(['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail']);
        else
            $entry->setTypes(['image']);

        $entry->setDisabled(false);
        $entry->setPosition($key);

        $entries[] = $entry;
    }

    $product->setMediaGalleryEntries($entries);

    $product->setImage($entries[0]->getFile());
    $product->setThumbnail($entries[0]->getFile());
    $product->setSmallImage($entries[0]->getFile());
    $this->_productRepository->save($product);
```

EDIT: after more investigation, it appears roles are only lost for 'all store views', in any other store views, the image rules are correctly detected.

Comment: I am facing this exact issue! Only difference is we are using default Magento import

Answer (score 0):

you need to used this to import product with images.

```
// Adding Image to product
$imagePath = $entries[0]->getFile(); // path of the image
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
$product->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Dhiren, but I think this is not a good thing to use the almost deprecated $product->save() method, that's why i use repositories to save my product, and I never manage to got it work with addImageToMediaGallery(), i added the line where I save the product to the code snippet for info

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the SQL command in your database:

```
SELECT *  FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE `value` LIKE 'no_selection'
```

For more info check [this support page](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002446014-Product-images-do-not-display-despite-Product-Edit-image-roles-) out.